# Chrome "About this page" is incorrect?

Tags: google, google-chrome

On my company website when viewed in Chrome, and you click on the little padlock icon next to the address, there is a "About this site" link at the bottom of the popup menu.  Trouble is it describes the wrong company.  Any ideas?  Anyone know where Google gets the data to populate it and how you go about getting it corrected?

Comment: I tried quite a few sites, but none of them have a "About this site" after clicking on the little padlock. Can you give an example of a site that has this? It doesn't need to be your company. Do you use a desktop or a mobile phone?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware try here. webmasters.stackexchange.com has it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it. This is what I get (in dark mode): https://imgbox.com/5qLuMEro

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, look at the last line: https://easycaptures.com/3396647785

Comment: No, sorry, cannot reproduce. It might be a setting somewhere. I'm not signed in, for instance, nor do I let Google check all the URL's I visit (enhanced security). However, doesn't that icon mean that you get a webpage? Could you post the link here?

Answer (score 0):

> it describes the wrong company

What do you mean with *wrong*?

There are primarily following sources for this information:

- Owner of HTTPS certificate for the domain,
- Entry in Google My Business, Wikipedia, DBpedia
- If identifiable, domain owner

Further sources are different and depend on certain case. This could be div. databases, web catalogues like Better Business Bureau or Dun & Bradstreet and so on.

Comment: I read _wrong_ as _different_. So you can see the "About this site" in the popup? How do you know that Chrome uses all these sources, or are you just guessing?

Comment: The website is https://fury.games.  It is owned by Fury Games Pty Ltd, whereas the "About this site" says Raw Fury AB, which is a different and unrelated company from a different country.  I don't understand where Google got the bad info from.  Fury Games Pty Ltd owns the domain and the SSL certificate.